# How to make the point to be spawned have the same coordinates to the "left" or "top" as the previous point

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to make it so that it is possible to connect the dice only with straight lines. But to do this, I need each subsequent dice to have a common "top" or "left" coordinate with the previous dice and at the same time a partial random is preserved.
Here is an example:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Игральные кости</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./dice.png">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="main-container">
        <div id="square-container">
        </div>
        <canvas id="overlay"></canvas>
    </div>

</body>

<script src="./script.js"></script>

</html>
```

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#main-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px
}

#square-container {
    width: 700px;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #dddddd;
    border: 5px solid #6b6b6b;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}


.js-is-target {
    position: absolute;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    /*background: blue;*/
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.square {
    top: 13px;
    left: 13px;
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
    background-size: contain;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.active-target {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```
//links to images of dice
var imgArr = [
    './dotsOnDice/dice1.jpg',
    './dotsOnDice/dice2.jpg',
    './dotsOnDice/dice3.jpg',
    './dotsOnDice/dice4.jpg',
    './dotsOnDice/dice5.jpg',
    './dotsOnDice/dice6.jpg'
]

//random number from 3 to 6
var randomAmount = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 3 + 1)) + 3;


//limit for recursion
var limitDice = 0;


function addDice() {
    // if the limit is equal to a random number, the recursion function is interrupted
    if (limitDice === randomAmount) {
        return
    }


    //random number from 2 to 5
    let randomAmountImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 2 + 1)) + 2;
    //random numbers for dice coordinates
    let position = {
        top: Math.random() * 520,
        left: Math.random() * 600
    }
    //saved previous coordinates for comparison
    let positionAfter = {
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    }

    //creating an id that we press later
    let idSquare = 'idSquare-' + limitDice;

    //subtract the previous coordinates from the current coordinates
    let top = position.top - positionAfter.top;
    let left = position.left - positionAfter.left;

    //we compare the positions of the previous coordinates to avoid a large number of overlaps
    if (top > 50 || left > 50) {
        positionAfter.top = position.top;
        positionAfter.left = position.left;

        //adding dice to the playing field
        let square = $('<div class="js-is-target"><div id="' + idSquare + '" class="square"></div></div>');
        square.appendTo('#square-container').css({ left: position.left + 'px', top: position.top + 'px' });     


        if (limitDice === 0) {
            $('#idSquare-0').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgArr[randomAmountImg] + ')');
        } else if (limitDice === 1) {
            $('#idSquare-1').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgArr[randomAmountImg] + ')');
        } else if (limitDice === 2) {
            $('#idSquare-2').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgArr[randomAmountImg] + ')');
        } else if (limitDice === 3) {
            $('#idSquare-3').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgArr[randomAmountImg] + ')');
        } else if (limitDice === 4) {
            $('#idSquare-4').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgArr[randomAmountImg] + ')');
        } else if (limitDice === 5) {
            $('#idSquare-5').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgArr[randomAmountImg] + ')');
        }
        limitDice += 1;
    }


    addDice();
}

addDice();


//here we store the canvas field
const canvas = document.getElementById('overlay');

//here we set the format in 2D for canvas
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//here we store the width and height of the canvas field. We set the height and width in HTML
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;

//in the variable we store the element that we clicked on
let targetEl = null;

//in the variable we store the coordinates of the center of the element we clicked on
let targetCenter = null;

//we check whether you clicked on the mouse or not
var down = false;

//coordinates of the pressed cursor mouseCoords
var mouseCoords = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}

//coordinates of the starting point
var centerCoords = {
    x: 760,
    y: 280
}


//в этой функции мы вычисляем где центр у прямоугольника
function getCenter(el) {
    //if not true, the function terminates and returns null
    if (!el) return null;
    //we save the coordinates in the rect constant using the getBoundingClientRect method
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    //returning the x and y coordinates. Here we calculate the center of the rectangle
    return {
        x: rect.left + rect.width / 2 + window.scrollX,
        y: rect.top + rect.height / 2 + window.scrollY,
    }
}


//connection points
function joinPoints(ctx, from, to) {
    //dotted line size
    const dashSize = 10;
    //draw a dotted line and write the size in the arguments
    ctx.setLineDash([dashSize]);
    //setting the gradient
    var stroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(from.x, from.y, to.x, to.y);
    //setting the color and position
    stroke.addColorStop(0, 'blue');
    stroke.addColorStop(1, 'red');
    //passing the colors to the strokeStyle property to set the color
    ctx.strokeStyle = stroke;
    //line thickness
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    //draw a contour (line)
    ctx.beginPath();
    //moves the contour point to the specified coordinates without drawing a line. Starting point
    ctx.moveTo(from.x, from.y);
    //adds a new contour point and creates a line to this point from the last specified point. End point
    ctx.lineTo(to.x, to.y);
    //draw a line
    ctx.stroke();
}


//when you click the mouse
$(document).mousedown(function (e) {
    down = true;
    mouseCoords.x = e.pageX;
    mouseCoords.y = e.pageY;
});


//when moving the mouse
$(document).mousemove(function (event) {
    if (down) {
        mouseCoords.x = event.pageX;
        mouseCoords.y = event.pageY;
        console.log(mouseCoords.x + ' ' + mouseCoords.y);
    }
});


//when we release the mouse button
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    down = false;
});


$(".js-is-target").hover(function (e) {
    if (down) {

        down = false;
        //we transmit data about which js-is-target we clicked on
        targetEl = e.target;
        //we write down where the center of the object we clicked on is. We calculate using the getCenter() function
        targetCenter = getCenter(targetEl);
        //changing the coordinates of the starting point
        centerCoords.x = targetCenter.x;
        centerCoords.y = targetCenter.y;
    }
});


//first we count, then we draw a line from ctx.lineTo to ctx.moveTo
function drwaDot() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx.moveTo(mouseCoords.x, mouseCoords.y);
    ctx.lineTo(centerCoords.x, centerCoords.y);
    ctx.stroke();
};


//the drawing interval of our line
var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
    if (down) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        joinPoints(ctx, { x: centerCoords.x, y: centerCoords.y }, mouseCoords);
    } else {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
}, 10);
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pbLef9oq/)

under the comment "//we compare the positions of the previous coordinates to avoid a large number of overlaps" changed the condition:
if(top < 10 || left < 10){
dice spawn code
}

That's what came out of it:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When I run your fiddle, I do not see the same types of images. It's not clear what steps should be taken to replicate the issue you are reporting.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).